# Search Right to left (Multiple Ranges)

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, search

All I have the below `For Each` loop which returns the last column which has a value <>0. This works fine although I'm sure there is a more efficient way.

```
    Dim LastColFcst As Integer
    For Each p In Range("E44:P44,S44:AD44,AG44:AR44,AU44:BF44,BI44:BU44")
    If p.Value <> 0 And p.Offset(-35, 0).Value = "Forecast" Then
    LastColFcst = p.Column
    End If
    Next p
```

I now wish to get the last column with a value <>0  for different rows 86,88,95,99. I can achieve this by copy and pasting my orginal code for four rows and having an IF Statement. However this seems like a very inefficient way to achieve a simple task. Sample code below; **EDIT Full sample (Long inefficient code posted below)

```
    Dim LastColFcst As Integer
For Each p In Range("E86:P86,S86:AD86,AG86:AR86,AU86:BF86,BI86:BU86")
If p.Value <> 0 And p.Offset(-77, 0).Value = "Forecast" Then
LastColFcst = p.Column
End If
Next p

For Each L In Range("E88:P88,S88:AD88,AG88:AR88,AU88:BF88,BI88:BU88")
If L.Value <> 0 And L.Offset(-79, 0).Value = "Forecast" And L.Column > LastColFcst Then
LastColFcst = L.Column
End If
Next L

For Each J In Range("E95:P95,S95:AD95,AG95:AR95,AU95:BF95,BI95:BU95")
If J.Value <> 0 And J.Offset(-79, 0).Value = "Forecast" And J.Column > LastColFcst Then
LastColFcst = J.Column
End If
Next J

For Each K In Range("E97:P97,S97:AD97,AG97:AR97,AU97:BF97,BI97:BU97")
If K.Value <> 0 And K.Offset(-88, 0).Value = "Forecast" And K.Column > LastColFcst Then
LastColFcst = K.Column
End If
Next K
```

Can anyone advise what's the best way to go about this scenario?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav the current loop is iterating through values within a summed row. In row 9 is "Actual" & "Forecast" dependant on the current month. The offset is checking this. (I have changed the offsets so they are correct in the scenario)

Comment: When you say `<>0` do you mean `-5` and `A` are ok?  Or does formula on the sheet ensure no letters are returned and only numbers greater than 0 for instance?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook -5 is okay (Any numeric number except 0) is okay. The formula on the sheet ensures there is no letters. (Its protected)